# There are no maximal $\mathbb{Z}$-submodules in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, abelian-groups

Is it true that $\mathbb{Q}$ viewed as  $\mathbb{Z}$-module (i.e. abelian group) has no maximal $\mathbb{Z}$-submodules? Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define action of $\mathbb Z$ on $\mathbb Q$ by $q\to nq$ for $q\in \mathbb Q$ and $n \in \mathbb Z $ it is trivial to check that $\mathbb Q$ is an $\mathbb Z$ module.

Now, Let $M$ be maximal submodule of $\mathbb Q$ then $\mathbb Q/M$ is an simple $\mathbb Z$ module. You can also say that it is cyclic module since by simplicity the module generated by elemet should be whole module.

Now, any cyclic $\mathbb Z$ submodule isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/(\langle a \rangle)$ and by simplicity we must have $a$ is prime so;

$$\mathbb Q/M\cong Z_p$$

Thus, we can have homomorphism from $\mathbb Q$ to $Z_p$ with kernel $M$ which is a contradiction.(why? you can simply think the homomorphism between two field $\mathbb Q$ and $Z_p$, it must be the trivial one.)

Comment: Note that the homomorphism from $\mathbb Q$ to $Z_p$ is only required to be a group homomorphism, but it is easy to show that any group homomorphism from $\mathbb Q$ to a field is a homomorphism of fields.

Comment: @AlexBecker: yeah you are right.

Comment: @AlexBecker: It is not a homomorphism of fields (not even a ring homomorphism), but we don't need that. Let $\varphi : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Z}/p$ be any surjective group homomorphism. Then for any rational number $x$ we have $0 = p \varphi(\frac{x}{p}) = \varphi(x)$ so $\varphi$ is the zero morphism which contradicts surjectivity.

Comment: @Dune Indeed, it seems the proof I was thinking of assumes $1\mapsto 1$ (which can be assumed) and injectivity (which cannot).