# Zorn's Lemma Application for Finding Maximal Submodule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I came across the following exercise in my algebra textbook.

> Let $M$ be a left $R$-module ($R$ is ring with unity $1_R$) and let
>   $N\subseteq M$ be a submodule such that $x\in M-N$ for some $x\in M$.
>   Show $M$ has a maximal submodule $L$ such that $L\supseteq N$ and
>   $x\not\in L$.

I guess I must use Zorn's lema.

**Sketch:** I defined $$\mathscr{F}:=\{L\subseteq M: L\neq M\ \textrm{is submodule}; L\supseteq N\quad \textrm{and}\quad x\not\in L\}.$$
Then $\mathscr{F}\neq \phi$ for $N\in\mathscr{F}$. Furthermore $(\mathscr{F}, \subseteq)$ is a poset. Given a totally ordered subset $\mathscr{T}$ of $\mathscr{F}$, it is easy to see $$L_0:=\bigcup_{L\in\mathscr{T}} L,$$ is an upper bound for $\mathscr{T}$. Hence $\mathscr{F}$ has a maximal element $\overline{L}$. In particular, $\overline{L}$ is a submodule of $M$, $\overline{L}\neq M$, $\overline{L}\supseteq N$ and $x\not\in \overline{L}$.

I'm almost there, how to show $\overline{L}$ is maximal with respect to the desired property?

Comment: Because you're element belong to $\mathscr{F}$ and every element of this poset has the desidered property.

Comment: Well, I was trying to use the definition I have of a maximal submodule: $L$ is a maximal submodule of $M$ if $(i)$ $L\neq M$; $(ii)$ If $N$ is any submodule of $N$ such that $L\subseteq N$ then $N=L$ or $N=M$..

Comment: Since $\bar L$ is a maximal element in $\mathscr{F}$ you have that for every other element $L \in \mathscr{F}$, that is every other submodule of $M$ such that $x \not \in L$ and $N \subseteq L$ you have that if $L \supseteq \bar L$ then $L = \bar L$.

This is the definition of maximal element of a poset.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true for arbitrary modules over unital rings. An example is $\mathbb Q$ as a module over $\mathbb Z$, which does not have a maximal submodule (see [There are no maximal $\mathbb{Z}$-submodules in $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734405/maximal-mathbbz-submodules-in-mathbbq)).

In your proof you have not shown that $L_0\neq M$, which is the source of this contradiction.

Comment: What is the condition needed for it to hold? This was an exercise of a book. Maybe the author adopts a convention that all modules will have some characteristic (which will ensure the validity of the statement).

Comment: If the module is finitely generated, it is sufficient.

Comment: So the statement of the exercise is certainly wrong (indeed it is not the first time it happens). Thanks.